# How to add state to my inputs using react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm trying to add state to my input so when the user changes the number it updates and it gets saved.
This is what my code looks like:

```
const PlanDistanceFieldset: FunctionComponent<PlanDistanceFieldsetProps> = (
  props
) => {
  const {register} = props
  const [showTip, setShowTip] = useState<boolean>(false)

  return (
    <>
      <div className={'form__parameter_row_wrapper'}>
        <div className={'form__parameter_field'}>
          <FormLabel text={'Plan Distance [m]'} />
        </div>

        <FormField
          label={'North-South Distance'}
          type={'number'}
          name={'north_south_distance'}
          defaultValue={500}
          required={true}
          register={register}
        />

        <FormField
          label={'East-West Distance'}
          type={'number'}
          name={'east_west_distance'}
          defaultValue={500}
          required={true}
          register={register}
        />
        <ToolTip
          onClick={() => {
            setShowTip(true)
         }}

        />
      </div>
```

I have tried adding useState and setState hooks to accomplish this but no luck.
The state does not save or update at all.
I tried to have the default value in a separate file and also adding it directly to useState, all the commented-out code is what I have tried so far. No errors get thrown, when I console log I can see the default value given.

Here's what I have tried:

```
import { defaultDistancePlan } from '../../Views/NewModelView/constants'
import FormField from '../Base/FormField'

const PlanDistanceFieldset: FunctionComponent<PlanDistanceFieldsetProps> = (
  props
) => {
  const {register} = props
  const [showTip, setShowTip] = useState<boolean>(false)

  const [ northDistance, setNorthDistanceValue] = useState(800)
  const [eastDistance, setEastDistanceValue] = useState(defaultDistancePlan.distanceEastValue)

//**handles north and east value dimension on modal view**//

// const handleNorthDistanceValue = e => {
//   setNorthDistanceValue(e.target.value)

//   // setNorthDistanceValue(e.target.value)
//   useEffect(()=>{
//     var updatedState
//     setNorthDistanceValue(currentState=>{    // Do not change the state by get the updated state
//        updatedState=currentState
//        return currentState
//     })
//     console.log(updatedState) // the current state.
//   })
// }



  const handleNorthDistanceValue = () => {
    setNorthDistanceValue(northDistance)
    
  }

  const handleEastDistanceValue = ()=> {
    setEastDistanceValue(eastDistance)

  }

  // useEffect(() => {
    console.log('north',northDistance)
  }, [northDistance]);
 
  console.log('north',northDistance)
  console.log('east',eastDistance)

  return (
    <>
      <div className={'form__parameter_row_wrapper'}>
        <div className={'form__parameter_field'}>
          <FormLabel text={'Plan Distance [m]'} />
        </div>

        
        <FormField
          label={'North-South Distance'}
          type={'number'}
          name={'north_south_distance'}
          value={northDistance}
          onChange={handleNorthDistanceValue}
          defaultValue={northDistance}
          required={true}
          register={register}
        />

      
        <FormField
          label={'East-West Distance'}
          type={'number'}
          name={'east_west_distance'}
          value={eastDistance}
          onChange={handleEastDistanceValue}
          defaultValue={defaultDistancePlan.distanceEastValue}
          required={true}
          register={register}
        />
        <ToolTip
          onClick={() => {
            handleNorthDistanceValue()
         }}

        />
      </div>
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

I messed up on the second part of the code ( has been fixed)! and as requested here is the FormField component:

```
const FormField: FunctionComponent<FormFieldProps> = (props) => {
  const {
    label,
    type,
    required,
    placeholder,
    name,
    register,
    rules,
    disabled,
    readonly,
    className,
    tip,
    defaultValue,
    value,
    step,
  } = props

  const [error, setError] = useState<string>()
  const [showTip, setShowTip] = useState<boolean>(false)

  const form_field = (
    <div className={['form__field', className].join(' ')}>
      {label && <FormLabel text={label} forID={name} />}

      <input
        id={name}
        className={`form__input ${readonly ? 'form__path' : ''}`}
        placeholder={placeholder as string}
        defaultValue={value || defaultValue}
        required={required}
        type={type}
        disabled={disabled}
        readOnly={readonly}
        step={step}
        {...register(`${name}`, {
          ...rules,
        })}
      />
    </div>
  )

  return (
    <>
      <div className={'form__field_wrapper'}>
        {form_field}

        {tip && <ToolTip onClick={() => setShowTip(true)} />}
      </div>

      {showTip && (
        <div className={'form__field_tip'}>
          <div>{tip}</div>
          <div>
            <FaWindowClose onClick={() => setShowTip(false)} />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      {error && <div className={'form__error'}>Error</div>}
    </>
  )
}

FormField.defaultProps = {
  type: 'text',
  required: false,
  placeholder: '',
  disabled: false,
  step: 1,
  register: () => {console.warn("Rendered FormField without a register.")}
}

export default FormField


export type FormFieldProps = {
  /**
   * The id that will represent this field in the form submit payload.
   */
  name: string
  /**
   * A human readable label that will appear next to the field.
   */
  label?: string
  /**
   * The html type attribute for the form field.
   */
  type?: string
  /**
   * Enables form validation to ensure field has been filled out.
   */
  required?: boolean
  /**
   * The human readable text that will appear as a placeholder before entry.
   */
  placeholder?: string | number
  /**
   * React hook form rules object for validation.
   */
  rules?: Record<string, unknown>
  /**
   * Register returned from useForm hook.
   */
  register?: any
  /**
   * Should this field be disabled?
   */
  disabled?: boolean
  /**
   * Is this field uneditable?
   */
  readonly?: boolean
  /**
   * Css class name for styling.
   */
  className?: string
  /**
   * Tooltip string to be displayed.
   */
  tip?: string
  /**
   * Default value for the field.
   */
  defaultValue?: string | number
  /**
   * Value for rerendering component with programmatic value.
   */
  value?: string | number
  /**
   * Html step attribute value for number fields.
   */
  step?: number
}
```

Comment: From where do you import `ParameterFormField`, `FormField`, `ToolTip` ? Can you update your code with those imports ?

Comment: @KavinduVIndika done!

Comment: @KavinduVIndika 
any suggestions on what the problem might be? thanks